# symfony2 namespaces using render(controller(..))

Tags: symfony

When I try to call:

```
{{ render(controller(
    'AppBundle:Default:_test'
)) }}
```

this one works, but if I create Admin folder and move my DefaultController there and call it like that:

```
{{ render(controller(
    'AppBundle:Admin:Default:_test'
)) }}
```

this error shows up

> ("Unable to parse the controller name
>   "AppBundle:Admin:Default:_test".")

What I'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you moved the controller from Default to Admin/Default folder, you should call it with

```
{{ render(controller(
    'AppBundle:Admin/Default:_test'
)) }}
```